Posting to Facebook using Python
I am attempting to create a Facebook posting using Jupyter notebook.
import facebook as fb

# Initialize the Graph API with your access token
access_token = 'code'
graph = fb.GraphAPI(access_token)

# Test API call
user_info = graph.get_object('me')
print(user_info)

# Create the post
post_message = "testing"
graph.put_object(parent_object='me', connection_name='feed', message=post_message)

However, there is an GraphAPIError: (#200).
In my Graph API Explorer, I have User Token with the following permission: user_events, user_photo, user_videos, user_post, public_profile.
May I know what else am I missing?

The possibility of posting to user profiles via API, has been removed ages ago.

Try putting apostrophes in GraphAPI  ('access_token')

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
